# Mapear dois arrays e deletar o item não encontrado

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho uma api em node e estou com a seguinte situação:

Eu sou o usuário master e crio um `usuário A`  para um funcionário qualquer. Esse `usuário A` possui as permissões

*Permissões usuário A*
`[criar_usuario,editar_usuario,receber_contas,editar_contas,ver_clientes]`

Então, esse `usuário A` cria um  outro `usuário B` no sistema com as permissões

*Permissões usuário B*
`[criar_usuario,deletar_usuario,deletar_contas,enviar_sms,excluir_registro]`

o que eu quero é mapear as permissões do `usuário A` e, caso ele crie ou edite o `usuário B`, o `usuário B` pode ter as mesmas permissões que o `usuário A` ou menos, mas nunca ter permissões que o usuário A não tem.

No exemplo acima, o `usuário B` pode ter:

`[criar_usuario,editar_usuario,ver_clientes]`

Mas nunca:

`[deletar_usuario,receber_contas,editar_clientes,ver_clientes]`

Tentei isso

```
let p = usuarioLogado.permissions; // permissões do usuário logado
let up = req.body.permissoes; // permissões do usuário que será criado ou editado

up.map((o, index) => {
     if (p.indexOf(o) <= -1) {
         up.splice(index, 1)
     }
})
```

mas não funciona, ficam resquícios das permissões q não podem ser aplicadas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) aplica uma função em um array e retorna um novo array onde cada elemento deste novo array é o resultado da função aplicada aos elementos do array anterior.

O que você parece estar querendo é utilizar o método [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), que retornará um novo array contendo apenas os elementos que passarem na "função de teste", ou seja, apenas os elementos cujo retorno da função foi `true` estarão no array de resultado.

Então para que você garanta que todas as permissões do usuário B estejam contidas nas permissões do usuário A, você pode usar o método [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) para testar se a permissão B está contido nas permissões A.

Exemplo:

```js
let perm_A = [
    "criar_usuario", 
    "editar_usuario", 
    "receber_contas", 
    "editar_contas", 
    "ver_clientes"
];

let perm_B_OK = [
    "criar_usuario",
    "editar_usuario",
    "ver_clientes"
];

let perm_B_Errado = [
    "deletar_usuario",
    "receber_contas",
    "editar_clientes",  // Essa permissão não pode
    "ver_clientes"
]


let allowed_perms_OK = perm_B_OK.filter(perm => perm_A.includes(perm));
console.log(allowed_perms_OK);

let allowed_perms_Errado = perm_B_OK.filter(perm => perm_A.includes(perm));
console.log(allowed_perms_Errado);
```

---

Se por algum motivo alguém for utilizar estes métodos no navegador, vale lembrar que o método [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) é relativamente recente (ou seja, problemas com IE). [Verifique aqui](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes) a compatibilidade antes de usar no seu projeto e considere usar [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) para garantir a compatibilidade no browser.

Comment: fernandosavio, era exatamente isso. Mto obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar  `Array.filter` e `Array.indexOf` em conjunto para verificar se as permições do usuário logado `p` já está em `up`.

Assim:

```
let p = usuarioLogado.permissions; // permissões do usuário logado
let up = req.body.permissoes; // permissões do usuário que será criado ou editado

let permissoes_up = p.filter((permicao) => (up.indexOf(permicao) !== -1))

console.log(permissoes_up)
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro no seu código está na comparação, acredito que se você trocar o `<=` por `>=` irá funcionar, o `indexOf` retorna a posição do elemento no array quando esse existe e retorna -1 quando não, então quando existir sempre será um valor maior que -1.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma

```
const usuarioA = ['criar_usuario', 'editar_usuario', 'receber_contas', 'editar_contas', 'ver_clientes']
let usuarioB = ['criar_usuario', 'deletar_usuario', 'deletar_contas', 'enviar_sms', 'excluir_registro']

usuarioB = usuarioB.filter(permissao => usuarioA.indexOf(permissao) !== -1)
```

Ai é só adaptar para a sua realidade.

Obs: Dei uma pequena refatora me baseando na resposta do outro rapaz.